# Sublime text 3 not building a python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-build

I am trying to build (Ctrl+B) a python (2.7 or 3) file in sublime text 3 in Ubuntu and I am expecting it to show some message at the bottom like

> [ Finished in 1.2 s ]

But it is showing nothing. I even reinstalled the sublime text after completely removing it but it still is not working. I tried to make a new build system for Python3 but building with that too shows nothing. Here is the build system I have (Python3)

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/env python3 ${file}",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}"
}
```

Other build systems which I have like for c++11 are working fine. Also I can use python2.7 as well as python3 in my terminal.

Comment: Does the thing you're building produce any output when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: Yes of course. It is a correct python program which I am trying to build in sublime.

Comment: What python program are you running? `while True: pass` will keep the program running forever (unless you cancel it), so never output something like `[ Finished in 1.2 s ]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42195200/revisions) to the question [Sublime text 3 not building a python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195200/sublime-text-3-not-building-a-python-file) by the OP [Sunil Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774977/sunil-kumar) under CC BY-SA 3.0.

> Thanks to @math2001's comment I realized that first line in my codes
> were user `input` and so it was waiting for user to type the input.